# Display/print text in Sumo-gui from Traci

Tags: python, simulation, sumo, traffic-simulation

I am learning Sumo/Traci with python.

I would like to display/print some values (retrieved from Traci with python) in the runnning Sumo-gui.

Is there anyway to display any text while the simulation is displayed and running?

Could you please point me out how could I do that?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can add a POI using [`traci.poi.add`](https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/TraCI/Change_PoI_State.html) (see also [here](https://sumo.dlr.de/pydoc/traci._poi.html#PoiDomain-add)) and configure sumo-gui to show its id or type wherever you want to put your text into.

Comment: Wow, this seems to be and might be a solution! Could you please post a reference or a link on that?

Comment: I added the links to the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to save data such as speedmean, density of road, and so on, you can use

```
 <edgeData id="datarout" begin="0" end="60" file="Traffic_Result4.xml"/>
```

in the additional file. (values are just as example)

If you want to see some values in the terminal in the middle of running, why do you not use print in python?

Comment: Unfortunatelly this is not the solution. I would like the data to be displayed IN the sumo gui window (so not on the terminal but right within the sumo gui interface window while running).